# include something in something

Tags: expressions

how can I describe in English that Institution B is becoming a part of Institution A?

In other words, can I say that: Institution A ***is including*** Institution B ***in***?

or

Institution A ***is having*** Institution B ***in***?

or

Institution A ***is taking*** Institution B ***in***?

Are "taking in/having in/including in" the accurate expressions to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

-Institution B is being absorbed by Institution A

-Institution B is being acquired by Institution A